# bcrypt segmentation fault error crashing webrick when new member action requested

Tags: ruby-on-rails, segmentation-fault, bcrypt

I'm trying to create authentication from scratch using bcrypt and I'm getting a webrick crash when I click the sign up link. The (very long) error message starts with:

```
Started GET "/assets/members.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-02 14:44:21 -0400
Served asset /members.js - 200 OK (0ms)
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/lib/bcrypt_ext.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]
```

Is there something wrong with the bcrypt gem? Should I reinstall ruby and/or rails? If so, how would I do that?

Comment: out of curiosity, why from scratch? Solutions like devise gem and others are very capable and mature, with plenty of support.

Comment: education. I'm trying to write my first real app with minimum plugins to learn as much as possible, and then rewrite it with more full-featured solutions.

Comment: Ah makes sense. These non informative errors are a massive pain, maybe some bcrypt dependency wasn't there or ruby was compiled without something it depends on. Sorry couldn't be much help.

Comment: what's the proper way to reset my environment? I'm using RVM if that matters.

Comment: You can use implode command with RVM, this should remove RVM, gemsets, all version of ruby that were installed using RVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reinstalling my environment, this problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar for me was fixed by simply wiping out my gems in the current RVM with `$ rvm gemset empty` then doing a `bundle install`.